# Google secret manager webpack issue

Tags: angular, google-secret-manager

Hi I'm trying to use google cloud secret manager but this error keeps showing up whenever I try to import the SecretManagerServiceClient I tried following the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/secret-manager) here but still can't make it run I also tried adding `fallback: true` to the constructor but it keep showing this error

There are multiple errors that are similar to this error message so I didn't copy them but essentially all error are coming from tunnel-agent

```
./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:6:12-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/[file path]/node_modules/tunnel-agent'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
        - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
```

btw I am using angular 14.2.12 and using google cloud secret manager version 5.2.0

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

```
async accessSecret() {
        const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient({ fallback: true });
        const [secret] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
            name: 'projects/my-project/secrets/my-secret',
        });

        // The secret payload is a base64-encoded string.sa
        const payload = secret.payload.data.toString();

        console.log(`The secret payload is: ${payload}`);
        console.log('test')
    }
```